# Read file and then use it from another button c#

Tags: c#, wav

I am trying to put together a form application to browse and play WAV files. Currently, it has two buttons - one to browse and select the WAV, the other one is to play. I have implemented the browse button and it is working ok. I checked it by playing the WAV sound within the button, as you can see:

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenFileDialog tarik = new OpenFileDialog();
    tarik.Title = "Browse...";
    tarik.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
    tarik.Filter = "Wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
    tarik.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (tarik.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        textBox1.Text = tarik.FileName;
        Stream tarik2 = tarik.OpenFile();
        SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(tarik2);
        snd.Play();
    }
}
```

I tested the code and it is working, but when I try to call the 'tarik' from another button:

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

As shown above, it says I am not allowed to do this.

Comment: what are you trying to do...

Comment: @MikeyMouse What makes you think this is ASP, and not say a winform or WPF application?

Comment: @Servy Oops, you're right. My mistake. Been staring at Asp.net code for too long. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables that you create in your browse handler are local variables (as they should be) which means they can't be accessed (because they don't exist) once the method ends.

You'll need to create an instance field, which exists for the entire lifetime of the object, to allow the other method to access it:

```
//new instance field.
private string tarikFileName;

private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog tarik = new OpenFileDialog();
    tarik.Title = "Browse...";
    tarik.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
    tarik.Filter = "Wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
    tarik.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (tarik.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        //store value in instance field
        tarikFileName = tarik.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = tarik.FileName;
        Stream tarik2 = tarik.OpenFile();
        using(SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(tarik2))
            snd.Play();
    }
}

private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tarikFileName != null)
    {
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(tarikFileName);
        using(SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(stream))
            snd.Play();
    }
}
```

Also note that the `SoundPlayer` should be disposed when you're done with it, so I've wrapped it in a `using` block to ensure that happens.

Answer (score 1):

In order to share data across the two methods you need some place to store the references.  In your case I would recommend pulling the file name from `textBox1.Text`. That way you don't have to worry about managing (opening/closing) the stream in multiple places.

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog tarik = new OpenFileDialog();
    tarik.Title = "Browse...";
    tarik.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop";
    tarik.Filter = "Wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
    tarik.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (tarik.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        textBox1.Text = tarik.FileName;
    }
}

private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using(Stream tarik2 = File.Open(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open))
        {
            SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(tarik2);
            snd.Play();
        }
}
```

Comment: The issue there is what happens if the user modifies that textbox?  You shouldn't store data like this in the UI.  The UI should just be for displaying data or getting input from the user.

Comment: @Servy I disagree.  I see this pattern often with a text box input and a "browse" icon that puts a file name in the text box.  The user then has the option of tweaking the path if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach:

1. Declare the `SoundPLayer` as a variable of your `Form`.
2. In the handler of `Browse` button get the file name, create a stream and initialize your `SoundPlayer` with it.
3. In the handler of `Play` button call the `Play()` method of the `SoundPlayer`.

Comment: The `SoundPlayer` is disposable, so ensuring it is disposed if you do that is going to be harder, and you'll end up consuming it's resources for much longer than is needed.